# FLUTTER DOCTOR [X] Android toolchain

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

Hi guys i have problem with android-SDK when i type on console "Flutter doctor" before show me this:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1500], 
locale pl-PL)
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup 
for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

I checked if the platform-tools and I think I have everything I need for the installation

**MY platform-tools screen**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yORFz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjIaQ.png)

**MY SDK FOLDER**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBs0N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> X Unable to locate Android SDK.

Add the location of the Android SDK in "Environment Variables In Windows 10"

https://programsbuzz.com/article/how-set-android-environment-variable-path-windows-10

Comment: Yeah  that's how it works! i must add path\\platform-tools and path\platforms

Answer (score 17):

This error means your "**Android SDK Command-line Tools are missing**"

1. Open Android Studio
2. In the Menu bar , click **Tools**(4th last)
3. choose **SDK Tools** panel
4. Tick Android **SDK Command-line Tools**
5. Click **Apply** at bottom of the window

IT WILL START DOWNLOADING the missing component

Answer (score 4):

Try running this command it works for me.I hope this will work for you as well.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Comment: when i do this i get : "Unable to locate Android SDK"

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by doing this:
Open Android studio, then go to

1. Appearance and behavior >
2. System settings >
3. Android SDK.
4. Then choose SDK Tools tab instead of the standard SDK Platforms.
5. Then choose Android SDK Command-line tools (latest) from the list and install it

After that, ran flutter doctor and if it shows that you have a problem with missing licenses, run the command it provides to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by installing the java. Follow the below steps.

1. Download the java from [oracle.com](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-mac)
2. Install it.
3. After that run `flutter doctor` command.
4. You will see toolchain error was gone.
5. Now run the `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Enjoy coding...